# pyspark launch issue ubuntu 16.04

Tags: pyspark, ubuntu-16.04

I just now installed apache-spark 3.1.2 on ubuntu 16.04. After installation and setting up PATH, SPARK_HOME, PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variables, when I try to launch pyspark I am getting below error:

```
$ $SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jan 26 2021, 13:30:48)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from pyspark.rdd import RDD, RDDBarrier
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 48, in <module>
    from pyspark.traceback_utils import SCCallSiteSync
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/traceback_utils.py", line 23, in <module>
    CallSite = namedtuple("CallSite", "function file linenum")
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 390, in namedtuple
    for k, v in _old_namedtuple_kwdefaults.items():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
Error in sys.excepthook:
```

I get same error when I try to import pyspark from python3

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jan 26 2021, 13:30:48)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyspark
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyspark/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from pyspark.rdd import RDD, RDDBarrier
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 48, in <module>
    from pyspark.traceback_utils import SCCallSiteSync
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyspark/traceback_utils.py", line 23, in <module>
    CallSite = namedtuple("CallSite", "function file linenum")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyspark/serializers.py", line 390, in namedtuple
    for k, v in _old_namedtuple_kwdefaults.items():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
Error in sys.excepthook:
```

I am clearly missing some dependency/configuration but unable to figure out which one?
I did notice that pyspark command references

```
/opt/spark/python/pyspark/
```

while python3 references

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyspark
```

Spark home is /opt/spark. spark-shell is working perfectly fine by the way. So it appears that the issue is with python.

Update: I installed spark 3.0.3 and the issue isn't happening. Looks like this is something specific to 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html#python-version-supported), Python 3.5.2 is not supported by Spark 3.1.2. Simply update Python to version 3.6 or above.